# ImportError: cannot import name 'Gridlayout' from 'kivy.uix.gridlayout' (C:\Users\ajay\kivy\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\gridlayout.py)

Tags: kivy-language

I have completely downloaded kivy but still, I am getting this error, please help!
`

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import Gridlayout


class alpha(Gridlayout):
   pass
class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
       return alpha()

MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
using "L" not "l"